# AsyncTask doesn't return value of boolean as expected

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

to be honest for me AsyncTask is most bothering method EVER,i never get used to what it does,

this is my AsyncTask code:

```
public class myAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Boolean, Boolean>{

boolean thisisresult=false;



         @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(String...urls){    


  try {
        socket = new Socket(server, port);
   }

   catch(Exception ec) {

    Log.i(LOGTAG,"Error connectiong to server:" + ec);
    return false;
  }
   String msg = "Connection accepted " + socket.getInetAddress() + ":" +  
socket.getPort();

   Log.i(LOGTAG, msg);

    try
    {
        sInput  = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        sOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    }
    catch (IOException eIO) {

        Log.i(LOGTAG,"Exception creating new Input/output Streams: " +   
eIO);
        return false;
    }

    try
    {




            EditText  u=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputuser);
            theuser = u.getText().toString();
            EditText p =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputpassword);
            thepass = p.getText().toString();
            EditText n =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.realname);
            thename = n.getText().toString();
            EditText m =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputmail);
            themail = m.getText().toString();
            EditText ph = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputphone);
            thephone = ph.getText().toString();





        int RID=RandomNumbers.Rgenerate();
        String newRID = Integer.toString(RID);


        sOutput.writeObject(theuser);
        sOutput.writeObject(thepass);
        sOutput.writeObject(thename);
        sOutput.writeObject(themail);
        sOutput.writeObject(thephone);
        sOutput.writeObject(newRID);
        sOutput.flush();
                Log.i(LOGTAG,"this"+theuser + thepass + thephone +   

themail + thename+ newRID);

        String REresponse = (String) sInput.readObject();


while(recieved==false)
{

if (REresponse.equals("('T','"+newRID+"')")){
        Log.i(LOGTAG,"you made it");
//  showthis=("اکانت با موفقیت ساخته شد");
    recieved = true;
    thisisresult=true;
}else if (REresponse.equals("('F','"+newRID+"')")){
        Log.i(LOGTAG,"you failed");
    //  showthis=("username تکراری است");
    recieved=true;
    thisisresult=true;
}else{

    //  showthis=("جوابی از سرور دریافت نشد");
        Log.i(LOGTAG,REresponse);
        Log.i(LOGTAG,"some thing is wrong");
            }
        }
    }


    catch (IOException eIO) {
//          display("Exception doing login : " + eIO);
        Log.i(LOGTAG,"Exception doing login : " + eIO);
        disconnect();


    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // success we inform the caller that it worked
    return true;
}

 }

protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alerttext);

if(result==true){
    tv.setText("done");

}
else{
    tv.setText("Not done");
}
```

the bottom my my async is supposed to return boolean value of true because i have set it to TRUE, but it doesnt, has any one mastered this method to help me?

Comment: Do you mean you want onPostExecute to return a boolean?

Comment: `the bottom my my async is supposed to return boolean` No... it's **void** it won't return anything. In facts, there's correctly no call to `return` in it.

Comment: well isnt it supposed to?!

Comment: well when i set it to static it returns error and asks to turn it into void ! i dont get what u mean there is no call to return, can you give me a tip there please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Android docs:

> The three types used by an asynchronous task are the following:
>
> - Params, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.

This is the first type that is passed. This allows you to pass something using the `execute` method

> - Progress, the type of the progress units published during the background computation.

This is passed as a parameter to the `onProgressUpdate` method

> - Result, the type of the result of the background computation.

This is the value that's passe from the `doInBackground` method to the `onPostExecute`

`onPostExecute` will always have a return type of void.

If your other method was blocking the UI thread while waiting for a return value from `AsyncTask`, it would negate the use of `AsyncTask`

Comment: so you cant return value of a AsyncTask? should i delete it from my library? i just need to pop up a toast for the IF loop there

Comment: Could you add the Toast to the `onPostExecute` method? It's called on the UI thread, so you won't have any problems

Comment: yes i could, but its dependant is inside the task ! i need to get a reference there, which not a bad idea, is it possible?

Comment: Can you post the method that displays the toast / calls `execute()`?

Comment: this is my execute, since all inputs are given from edittext, inside the atask,  public void doit(){
myAsync sync = new myAsync();
sync.execute();
}

Comment: Can you edit your post, and add the method with your Toast in there? I might be able to help you move the Toast